# How many days AWS Resource Share invitation will be present in AWS after accepting it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to know exactly how many days AWS Resource Share invitation will be present in AWS?

```
[karthik@server]$ aws ram get-resource-share-invitations  --profile dev2
{
    "resourceShareInvitations": [
        {
            "status": "ACCEPTED",
            "invitationTimestamp": 1585154333.8,
            "receiverAccountId": "---",
            "resourceShareName": "resource-share-mgmt",
            "resourceShareArn": "arn:aws:ram:us-east-1:---:resource-share/5eb789e4-dcd7-6164-bd27-9a9685c121e6",
            "resourceShareInvitationArn": "arn:aws:ram:us-east-1:---:resource-share-invitation/ea66f33d-200f-4585-8a63-3f1102fx981c",
            "senderAccountId": "---"
        }
    ]
}
[karthik@server]$ date
Thu Apr  2 11:29:14 UTC 2020
```

Above is the resource share I created recently 8 days ago in one of the AWS Account.

But in another account I did the same couple of months ago, but I don't see it in now.

```
[karthik@server]$ aws ram get-resource-share-invitations  --profile dev
{
    "resourceShareInvitations": []
}
```

So, what is the exact number of days validity for the AWS resource share invitations after accepting the invitation?

Couldn't able to find the information in AWS documentation

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the invitation anymore.

```
[karthik@server]$ aws ram get-resource-share-invitations  --profile dev2
{
    "resourceShareInvitations": []
}
[karthik@server]$ date
Fri Apr  3 06:31:45 UTC 2020
```

For me, after 9 days the invitation doesn't exist anymore.

[image]